# unexpected fi in bash script

Tags: bash, if-statement

This is the script and I keep getting an unexpected fi error. What am I missing? .. (I started using [] for the if statement but since I'm using this command I deleted the [] .. Is it ok this way?)

```
if type "java" 2>&1;
    then
        echo "All ok . . . ";
        exit                                                                                                                                              
    else
        read -n1 -r -p "Yo need to install"
        while true; do
            echo "Want to install??"
            select yn in "y" "n"; do
                case $yn in
                    y ) echo "Installing here..."; break;;
                    n ) echo "Ok... stopping..."; exit;;
                esac
            done
        exit
fi
```

thanks!

Comment: You may find a tool like [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) helpful for figuring out basic syntax errors in the future. Here it points to the `do` saying "Couldn't find 'done' for this 'do'.", and then to the `fi` saying "Expected 'done' matching previously mentioned 'do'."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while` ends with `done`, not `exit`. Try this:

```
if type "java" 2>&1;
    then
        echo "All ok . . . ";
        exit                                                                                                                                              
    else
        read -n1 -r -p "Yo need to install"
        while true; do
            echo "Want to install??"
            select yn in "y" "n"; do
                case $yn in
                    y ) echo "Installing here..."; break;;
                    n ) echo "Ok... stopping..."; exit;;
                esac # <-- ending `case`
            done     # <-- ending `select`
        done         # <-- while ends with `done`, not `exit`!
fi                   # <-- ending `if`
```

Comment: Great! That was the problem... could you tell me why to use `done` again, please?? ... the first one end the `while` .. and the second the `else`??

Comment: @AAlvz: Every `do` ends with a `done`. You have one for `while` and one for `select`.

Comment: @AAlvz - I edited my answer to show which endings match what. The first `done` matches the `select ... do`, whereas the second matches the `while ... do`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an `exit` before the last `fi`; I suppose that should be a `done`.